# Deleting entities at certain coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Heyo,
I was wondering if there is anyway to test for a certain entity at some preordained coordinates, then delete only those entities at those specific coordinates? More simply - is there a way to delete entities at certain coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the @e selector with the `x`, `y`, and `z` selectors:

```
/kill @e[x=<X>,y=<Y>,z=<Z>,r=1]
```

Comment: If this answer solved your question please click the checkmark below the score to accept the answer.

Comment: A little back up question, but what about specific entities? Like only cobblestone and acacia wood planks, but still at a certain coordinate?

Comment: @SMILIECHICKEN Cobblestone & Acacia wood planks are blocks not entities....

Comment: Oh, my bad D: But there is no way to destroy only specific *items* on a certain coordinate? Example ~ I want a player to drop a "key", or in this case a tripwire hook, onto a diamond block at 63 70 45, and then to have the "key" destroyed and have a firework summoned. However, if it's not a tripwire hook that was dropped there, then nothing would happen.

Comment: You will need scoreboards for that. Mark the entity and select it. There should be an answer to that somewhere else on the site.